# How to select table user in yii2?

Tags: php, postgresql, yii2

i have a trouble, when select table user in yii2 , data no show up

[image: User Table]

[image: Result]

```
 $sqlGetuser = "select * from user ";
                            $sqlquery = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sqlGetuser)->query();
                            foreach($sqlquery as $row){
                                // echo $row;
                                // echo "saya";
                                echo $row['username'];
                            }
```

Comment: Can you print out the contents of `$row`?

Comment: Ya..
i change my code.. this...  $sqlGetuser = "select * from user ";
                                $sqlquery = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sqlGetuser)->queryOne();
                                print_r($sqlquery); this result :Array ( [current_user] => local )

Comment: You're probably running into problems with the table name "user" as it's a reserved word. Try changing your query to `select * from "user"` or renaming the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in this line:

```
$sqlquery = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sqlGetuser)->query();
```

[query()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#query%28%29-detail) returns `yii\db\DataReader`. To return array of rows use [queryAll()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#queryAll%28%29-detail):

```
$rows = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sqlGetuser)->queryAll();
```

If you want to use `query()`, you need to read data differently:

```
$command = $connection->createCommand('SELECT * FROM "user"');
$reader = $command->query();

while ($row = $reader->read()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

// equivalent to:
foreach ($reader as $row) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

// equivalent to:
$rows = $reader->readAll();
```

See more in [official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-datareader.html).

Also quote table name as adviced since it's reserved word.